# What is the Rails Way to iterate through multi-step associations in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 project with Product.

```
:product has_many :product_properties
:product has_many :properties, :through => :product_properties

:product_property belongs_to :product
:product_property belongs_to :property

:property has_many :product_properties
:property belongs_to :property_type
```

There is a attribute "sequence" on :property_type and :property.

I want to display these in order of sequence at those two levels. The only way I can think of to do this is to loop through each of them in the model and put the sequence number in a hash so that I can sort on that. Very very ugly.

I know that I could add an "order" on the has_many relationships, but that doesn't solve my belongs_to sort coming from my many-to-many relation.

The reason I think I need to use a hash is because I want my display to be:

Property Type 1 *********
 * Property 1: value
 * Property 2: value
 * Property 3: value

Property Type 2 *********
 * Property 4: value
 * Property 5: value

If I loop through the whole collection I'm going to get duplicates of my property types, unless I put some ugly "previous value" and "current value" comparisons in there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing. It is a combination of ":has_many, :through" relationships and AREL, and it allows me to display nested relationships in a pretty way without a whole lot of code.

```
<% for pt in PropertyType.where("name not in ('Interchanges','Description')").order(:name) %>
    <% next unless pt.product_properties.where(:product_id => @product.id).first %>
    <h2><%= pt.name %></h2>
    <p>
        <% for pp in @product.product_properties.includes(:property).order("properties.name") %>
            <%= pp.property.name %>: <%= pp.value %><br />
        <% end %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The `PropertyType.where` call belongs in a model, not in the view. Rails is an MVC framework: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 0):

I've got some ideas, not sure if they'll work, and I'm still using rails 2.3

Idea 1-
add to your models
default_scope :order => 'sequence'

Idea 2-

Product.find(:all, :include =>{:product_properties => {:properties => :property_type} }, :order=>" products.sequence, property_types.sequence")

note: the table may not be called property_types in the query, but you can look at the logs and see what sort of alias it was give by rails.

Last resort

a.sort_by {|a| a}

(no need to create a hash)

Comment: I edited the post. The reason I need a hash is because I have this hugely detailed collection, but I want to display in chunks like I've listed above.